# Inject SqlConnection to ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm a newcomer to the Dependency Injection world and I've read few articles on this subject, mostly based on the repository pattern.

But I would like to inject a SqlConnection to every Controller. Is there any simple yet comprehensive article or example?